# Diffeomorphism from parametrized torus to set of zeros

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am asked to prove that the differentiable map
$$ h \colon S^1 \times S^1 \to M,~~(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2) \mapsto (\sqrt{2}+b_1) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + b_2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
is a diffeomorphism where $M$ is the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that satisfy
$$ (x^2 +y^2+z^2+1)^2 = 8 (x^2 +y^2).$$
I already understood that $S^1 \times S^1$ is a torus and that $M$ also forms a torus so I intuitively understand that it has to be true. To prove the claim I tried to find an inverse map of $h$, $h^{-1}: M \to S^1 \times S^1,~~(x,y,z) \mapsto (a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2)$ but I can not find a way to "get out" $b_1$ since I only seem to know $b_2$ and the fact that $b_1^2+b_2^2 = 1$ which gives me only $b_1 = \pm \sqrt{1-b_2^2}$.
I also proved that $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ using the fact that $M = f^{-1}(0)$ for $0$ a regular value of the following map
$$ f \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R},$$
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (x^2+y^2+z^2+1)^2 - 8(x^2+y^2).$$
Am I just not seeing the right way to find $h^{-1}$ or is there some other way of proving that $h$ is a diffeomorphism?

Comment: First, why do you need $h^{-1}$? A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. But if you insist, perhaps parametrizing the circles trigonometrically will help.

Comment: That doesn’t imply that it is also a diffeomorphism or can I deduce that from it being a homeomorphism in another step?

Comment: If you check the derivative always has rank $2$ it does.

Comment: I think I need $h^{-1}$ to prove that it is a diffeomorphism. Once I have $h^{-1}$ and can show that it is also differentiable I have shown that h is a diffeomorphism

Comment: Do you know the inverse function theorem?

Comment: Yes. In my lecture we used it to prove that a differentiable function is a local diffeomorphism at a regular point - I was not sure how to extend it to a global diffeomorphism

Comment: A bijective smooth map with nonsingular derivative at each point is à diffeomorphism.

Comment: Ok I see. Then h being a homeomorphism and having nonsingular derivative at each point proves the claim - thanks a lot!